# Consulta en mysql para seleccionar el registro actual dependiendo de la fecha

Tags: mysql

Me podrian ayudar con una consulta

tengo esta consulta

```
select jornada, min(date_game_large) as date_start, max(date_game_large) as date_end from mi_tabla 
group by jornada order by jornada
```

en la que me devuelve esto:

```
journay     date_start      date_end
1           1501023600      1501115400
2           1501628400      1501722000
3           1502233200      1502326800
4           1502838000      1502929800
5           1504047600      1504227600
6           1505257200      1505350800
16          1508886000      1508972400
```

que es cuando comienza la jornada y cuando termina y de ahi quisiera obtener la jornada en la que nos encontramos por la fecha que esta en formato timestamp

lo intente asi:

```
select jornada, min(date_game_large) as date_start, max(date_game_large) as date_end from mi_tabla group by jornada order by jornada
where (date_start BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AND date_end)
```

pero me marca ese error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'date_start' in 'where clause'
```

Me podrian ayudar porfavor

Gracias
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

El error esta en que estas tratando de filtrar por un alias y no por el nombre de la columna en si, en lugar de usar date_start en el where deberias usar min(date_game_large).

```
    select jornada, min(date_game_large) as date_start, max(date_game_large) as date_end from mi_tabla group by jornada order by jornada
where (min(date_game_large) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AND date_end)
```

Comment: Exacto, si cambias el primer alias en el WHERE te marcaría el segundo como columna desconocida también. Cambiando los alias por el nombre del campo debería de no arrojarte problema alguno.
Ya nos comentas si te fue bien :)